# Scala: Default Value for a Map of Tuples

Tags: scala

Look at the following `Map`:

```
scala> val v = Map("id" -> ("_id", "$oid")).withDefault(identity)
v: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,java.io.Serializable] = Map(id -> (_id,$oid))
```

The compiler generates a `Map[String,java.io.Serializable]` and the value of `id` can be retrieved like this:

```
scala> v("id")
res37: java.io.Serializable = (_id,$oid)
```

Now, if I try to access an element that does not exist like this...

```
scala> v("idx")
res45: java.io.Serializable = idx
```

... then as expected I get back the key itself... but how do I get back a tuple with the key itself and an empty string like this?

```
scala> v("idx")
resXX: java.io.Serializable = (idx,"")
```

I always need to get back a tuple, regardless of whether or not the element exists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `.withDefault(identity)` you can use

```
val v = Map("id" -> ("_id", "$oid")).withDefault(x => (x, ""))
```

`withDefault` takes as a parameter a function that will create the default value when needed.

This will also change the return type from useless `Serializable` to more useful `(String, String)`.